# How to properly create a consumer for integration test in order to verify a message was pushed to kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using avro to generate a java class (Heartbeat) and I'm using Spring cloud messaging Processor in order to push a message to kafka using this Heartbeat class.

So here is my service:

```
@Service
public class HeartbeatServiceImpl implements HeartbeatService {

  private Processor processor;

  public HeartbeatServiceImpl(Processor processor) {
    this.processor = processor;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean sendHeartbeat(Heartbeat heartbeat) {
    Message<Heartbeat> message =
        MessageBuilder.withPayload(heartbeat).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "MY_KEY").build();
    return processor.output().send(message);
  }

}
```

I have this consumer on my test package:

```
@Component
public class HeartbeatKafkaConsumer {


  private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  private String payload = null;

  @KafkaListener(topics = "HEARTBEAT")
  public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
    this.payload = consumerRecord.toString();
    this.latch.countDown();
  }


  public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
    return latch;
  }

  public Object getPayload() {
    return payload;
  }

}
```

Now on my actual test class I have this:

```
public class HeartbeatServiceImplIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private HeartbeatServiceImpl heartbeatService;

  @Autowired
  private HeartbeatKafkaConsumer heartbeatKafkaConsumer;

  @Test
  public void assertHeartbeatPushedToKafka() throws InterruptedException {
    Heartbeat heartbeat =
        Heartbeat.newBuilder().setID("my-Test ID").setINPUTSOURCE("my-Test IS")
            .setMSGID("my-Test 123").setMSGTIME(12345l).setRECEIVEDTIME(12345l).build();

    boolean isMessageSent = heartbeatService.sendHeartbeat(heartbeat);
    assertThat(isMessageSent).isTrue();

    heartbeatKafkaConsumer.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    assertThat(heartbeatKafkaConsumer.getLatch().getCount()).isEqualTo(0L);
    assertThat(heartbeatKafkaConsumer.getPayload()).isEqualTo(heartbeat);

  }

}
```

I can see the message does arrive on kafka by running ksql. So the message is there as expected.
I also receive a message from my heartbeatKafkaConsumer, but when I do the assertion I'm getting this error:

```
Expecting:
 <"ConsumerRecord(topic = HEARTBEAT, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 4, CreateTime = 1622134829899, serialized key size = 12, serialized value size = 75, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = [B@765aa560, value = [B@3582e1cd)">
to be equal to:
 <{"ID": "my-Test ID", "TYPE": "null", "MSG_ID": "my-Test 123", "MSG_TIME": 12345, "RECEIVED_TIME": 12345, "INPUT_SOURCE": "my-Test IS", "SBK_FEED_PROVIDER_ID": "null", "SBK_FEED_PROVIDER_NAME": "null"}>
```

Now I tried to read in many different ways from my HeartbeatKafkaConsumer but I just couldn't make the value properly parse back to a Heartbeat.

How do I consume from kafka as a Heartbeat so I can test it against the message originally sent?
I'm not even being able to retrieve as a string either.

Oh, and here's my applicaiton.properties configuration for kafka:

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.producer.useNativeEncoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.useNativeEncoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=HEARTBEAT
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=HEARTBEAT
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.key.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.key.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.specific.avro.reader=true
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=myclient
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `consumerRecord.value()` instead of toString.

It will be a `byte[]` which you can pass into an ObjectMapper to deserialize it as a `Heartbeat`.

Or, simply configure the consumer to use a `JsonDeserializer` and `consumerRecord.value()` will be the heartbeat. You will need to configure the deserializer to tell it which type to create.

Third (and simplest) option is to add a `JsonMessageConverter` `@Bean` (boot will wire it into the listener container) and change your method to

```java
  @KafkaListener(topics = "HEARTBEAT")
  public void receive(Heartbeat heartbeat) {
      ...
  }
```

The framework tells the converter what type to create, from the method signature.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion